# Is there a simple code to allow certain user(s) access to see command buttons?

Tags: vba, security, ms-access, userform

Okay, I am having difficulties coding security behind my user form. Let me give you guys the rundown. I created this make table "tblPermissionTypes" that basically has two field in there "ID" & "EmployeeType_ID". The ID field represents Security level of access 0 through 2, and EmployeeType_ID is the title: 0 = Requestor, 1 = Admin, and 2 = Printer.

With that being said I have another table "tblEmployees" with the same field "EmployeeType_ID", I manually set the 0s, 1s, & 2s. This table also contains all employees UserNames

Finally, I have another table "tblPermission" that contains three fields "EmployeeType_ID", "FormName",  and "HasAccess"

My end result is being whenever this tblPermission has a Checkbox under the field HasAccess I want to grant access based on the EmployeeType_ID field to communicate back to the table "tblEmployees", but in this case I want them to only be able to see a button that contains that certain form.

```
Private Sub cmdClick_Click()

Dim strSQL As String
Dim permission As String

If permission = ("fOSUserName") = True Then
Run strSQL
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblEmployees WHERE "
strSQL = strSQL & "tblEmployees.Five2 =" & ("fOSUserName") & """, = False 
Then

MsgBox "You do not have permission!", vbExclamation

Else'
cmdButton.Visible True

End If

NOTE: fOSUserName, is a function I created basically the same thing as 
Environ("UserName") 


Debug.Print strSQL
```

Comment: Don't put function calls between quote marks.

Comment: A better name for EmployeeType_ID field in tblPermissionTypes would be EmployeeTypeTitle.

Answer (score 0):

Function calls should not be within quote marks. You construct an SQL statement but then don't properly use it. You declare and use variable `permission` but don't set the variable - it is an empty string. Need form name as a search criteria. Couple of other syntax errors but they will go away with this suggested code. Run this code in form Open event to disable button and don't even give unauthorized users opportunity to click. Don't annoy them with a popup message that emphasizes their lowly status in hierarchy.

You need to build a query that joins tblEmployees to tblPermission so that UserName, FormName, HasAccess fields are all available then reference that query in search for permission.

A DLookup could serve here.

```
Me.buttonNameHere.Visible = Nz(DLookup("HasAccess", "queryNameHere", _
     "UserName='" & fOSUserName & "' AND FormName='FormNameHere'"), 0)
```